# Assign filetype to a software by script

Tags: powershell, registry, file-extension, file-type

Would like to assign certain filetypes to a software by script (preferably by PowerShell or .reg) in Windows 11.

This PowerShell-Code worked fine over one year ago:

```
cmd /c "assoc .rhistory = rhistory_file"
cmd /c "ftype rhistory_file = "`"C:\Program Files\RStudio\rstudio.exe`" `"%1`"""
```

Tried also something like this:

```
$RStudioPath = "C:\Program Files\RStudio\rstudio.exe"
$FileType = ".rhistory"
$FileAssociation = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey($FileType)
$FileAssociation.SetValue("", "RStudio.rhistory")
$FileAssociation.CreateSubKey("shell")
$Command = $FileAssociation.CreateSubKey("shell\open\command")
$Command.SetValue("", "`"$RStudioPath`" `"%1`"")
```

Can somebody help?
Thank you.

Comment: What was the result when that was done? Were there error messages? Did anything change?

Comment: No Errors, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've run them *with elevation*, i.e. as administrator, your commands look correct *in principle*.

However, on a per-filename-extension basis, *user-specific overrides* can be in place on a given machine, via *File Explorer*, namely:

- If the current user has interactively chosen to *always* open a file with a given extension with a specific program, by right-clicking on such a file in File Explorer, selecting `Open with > Choose another app`, selecting the app of interest and then clicking on `Always`
- Through a mechanism that is unclear to me, *some* applications - notably [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - manage to install such a persistent override even if you click on `Just once` or even just *drag* a file to an open Visual Studio Code windoe.

Either way, in order to *undo* such an override, you'll need to remove it *from the registry* at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\<.extension>`; in your case (using PowerShell's `HKCU:` drive to refer to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive):

```
#requires -RunAsAdmin
# Assumes that the key exists.
Remove-Item -Recurse HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.rhistory
```

The **caveat** is that you'll have to repeat the above whenever you (the current user) choses to open a file with the extension of interest with an application such as Visual Studio Code again - even with the intent of doing so *ad hoc only*.